# Creating Function in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm beginning with octave.  I've created a file called squareThisNumber.m in My Documents with the following code:

```
function y = squareThisNumber(x)
y = x^2;
```

I set the directory to look at My Documents with

```
cd 'C:\Users\XXXX\My Documents'
```

I type "squareThisNumber(3)" into octave, and all I'm getting is "Error: 'squareThisNumber' undefined near line 3 column 1."  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

When I type ls into octave, I get "error: ls: command exited abnormally with status 127".  Did I not install Octave correctly?

Comment: Welcome. You have to make sure the filename matches the function name *and* that the file is in the directory `My Documents`.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see both the filename and function name are matching, and the file is in the My Documents folder

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What version of GNU Octave are you using? We're at [3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you place the `end` keyword at the end? Code example below works perfectly for me

https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/function-example

```
% Welcome to Saturn's MATLAB-Octave API.
% Delete the sample code below these comments and write your own!

function y = squareThisNumber(x)
y = x^2;
end

squareThisNumber(9)
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior sure does seem like there's a problem with octave's [current working directory](http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html3/octave_183.html#SEC305).   Does the command **dir** or **pwd** also have the same problem?

But you might be able to ignore all of that by

```
addpath("C:\Users\XXXX\My Documents");
```

Comment: I don't think adding to the path is a solution here, he should be able to simply change the directory. Do you experience the same error message? What version of GNU Octave?

Comment: @juliohm **cd** also works for me, I also use version 3.8.  I had hoped to avoid whatever was going wrong with **cd** by not using **cd**.  It's a little late, but I see now this is better as a comment.